# Admob closes app after closing ad?

Tags: android, android-activity, crash, admob

I have one Activity in my app. Now I wanted to add an Admob interstitial banner. Unfortunately the old activity is also closed when the user closes the ad.

I added something like this:

```
 interstitial = new InterstitialAd(this, "*************");
        // Create ad request
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest();
        // and begin loading your interstitial
        interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
        interstitial.setAdListener(this);
```

And started the ad by using

```
if (interstitial.isReady()){
interstitial.show();
}
```

The representation of the app is working fine.

What can I do to solve the problem?

Comment: override the onBackpressed() method to handle this.

Comment: I do not know how this can help me. I overrode this method and it still does not work. Admob seems to override the MainActivity.

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute in your AndroidManifest.xml file, like **android:noHistory="true"** You must delete this. it solves the problem

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
private boolean isAddShown = false;
```

make this `isAddShown = true` when the add is visible

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(!isAddShown){
        super.onBackPressed();
    }else{

       isAddShown = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: But the problem is also there if I press on the little symbol to close the app.

Comment: There is no option to hide an interstitial.

Comment: I tested it. But the same result. The problem seems to be that the MainActivity is overridden by the ad.

Comment: As a heads up, super.onBackPressed() calls finish(), which in turn will call setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED). So if you are planning to return a result to the parent activity, you have to do it here, as well as in your onPause() method. SetResult() can only be called once, and all subsequent calls are ignored.